# Query to look up comment in one table, username in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a MySQL table called "login" with the following structure:

```
loginid, username, password, email, actcode, disabled, activated, created, points
```

I am using another MySQL table called "comment" with the following structure:

```
commentid, loginid, submissionid, comment, datecommented
```

For a given "submisssionid", I would like to print out the following information from the table "comment":

-The fields "comment" and "datecommented".

At the same time, I would like to print out the following from the table "login":

-The "username" that corresponds to the "loginid" for each row being row being selected from the table "comment".

How can I do this?

I tried the code below but it did not work.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$submission = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submission']);
$submissionid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submissionid']);


    $sqlStr = "SELECT 
                    c.loginid
                    ,c.submissionid
                    ,c.comment
                    ,c.datecommented
                    ,l.username
                    ,COUNT(c.commentid) countComments
                 FROM 
                    comment c
                WHERE
                    c.submissionid = $submissionid  
                INNER
                 JOIN
                    login l
                   ON
                    c.loginid = l.loginid
                 GROUP
                    BY
                     c.submissionid
                 ORDER  
                    BY 
                     c.datecommented DESC
                 LIMIT 
                     100";          

    $result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

    $arr = array(); 
    echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1">'.$row["comment"].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</a>'.$row["datecommented"].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT comment.comment, comment.datecommented, login.username
FROM comment
LEFT JOIN login ON comment.loginid=login.loginid
WHERE submissionid=$submissionid
ORDER BY comment.datecommented DESC 
LIMIT 100";
```